# Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimation for Linear Mixed Model

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, profile-likelihood, reml

The maximum likelihood estimation procedure for linear mixed model is described [in this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/estimating-parameters-in-linear-mixed-effects-models.html). It seems to me that something is wrong there.

In their Restricted Maximum Likelihood section the first equation is:

$$P(\boldsymbol y|\boldsymbol\theta,\sigma^2)=\int P(\boldsymbol y|\boldsymbol\beta,\boldsymbol\theta,\sigma^2) P(\boldsymbol \beta)d\boldsymbol\beta=\int P(\boldsymbol y|\boldsymbol\beta,\boldsymbol\theta,\sigma^2)d\boldsymbol\beta.$$

How can be $\int P(\boldsymbol y|\boldsymbol\beta,\boldsymbol\theta,\sigma^2) P(\boldsymbol \beta)d\boldsymbol\beta=\int P(\boldsymbol y|\boldsymbol\beta,\boldsymbol\theta,\sigma^2)d\boldsymbol\beta $ ?

Where is the $P(\boldsymbol \beta)$ in the last integral ?

- Also what is the posterior distribution $P(\boldsymbol\beta|\boldsymbol y,\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_R,\hat\sigma^2_R)$ ?

What will be the expression of the posterior distribution ?